# Variables getting reset after the while read loop that reads from a pipeline

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop, subshell

```
initiate () {
read -p "Location(s) to look for .bsp files in? " loc
find $loc -name "*.bsp" | while read
do
    if [ -f "$loc.bz2" ]
    then
        continue
    else
        filcount=$[$filcount+1]
        bzip $loc
    fi
    if [ "$scan" == "1" ]; then bzipint $loc
    fi
    echo $filcount    #Correct counting
    echo $zipcount    #Correct counting
    echo $scacount    #Correct counting
    echo $valid       #Equal to 1
done

echo $filcount    #Reset to 0
echo $zipcount    #Reset to 0
echo $scacount    #Reset to 0
echo $valid       #Still equal to 1
}
```

I'm writing a bash shell script to use `bzip2` to zip up all `.bsp` files inside a directory. In this script I have several variables for counting totals (files, successful zips, successful integrity scans), however I seem to have run into a problem.

When `find $loc -name "*.bsp"` runs out of files to give the `while read` and `while read` exits, it zeros out `$filcount`, `$zipcount` and `$scacount` (all of which are changed (increased) inside `initiate ()`, `bzip ()` (which is called during `initiate ()`) or `bzipint ()` (which is also called in `initiate ()`).

In order to test if it's something to do with variables changing inside `initiate ()` or other functions accessed from it, I used echo `$valid`, which is defined outside of `initiate ()` (like `$filcount`, `$zipcount`, etc.), but is not changed from another function inside `initiate ()` or inside `initiate ()` itself.

Interestingly enough, `$valid` does not get reset to 0 like the other variables inside initiate.

Can anyone tell me why my variables magically get reset when while read exits?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ran into this problem yesterday.

The trouble is that you're doing `find $loc -name "*.bsp" | while read`. Because this involves a pipe, the `while read` loop can't actually be running in the same bash process as the rest of your script; bash has to spawn off a subprocess so that it can connect the the stdout of `find` to the stdin of the `while` loop.

This is all very clever, but it means that any variables set in the loop can't be seen after the loop, which totally defeated the whole purpose of the `while` loop I was writing.

You can either try to feed input to the loop without using a pipe, or get output from the loop without using variables. I ended up with a horrifying abomination involving both writing to a temporary file AND wrapping the whole loop in `$(...)`, like so:

```
var="$(producer | while read line; do
    ...
    echo "${something}"
done)"
```

Which got me var set to all the things that had been echoed from the loop. I probably messed up the syntax of that example; I don't have the code I wrote handy at the moment.

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks for the clarification. Yeah, this is definitely going to cause some complications... I might have to end up using a temporary file or two to get around this, like you did. :P

Comment: Hello, people reading this in the future, ten years or more after this question was posted! Please use [the process substitution version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7314435/785213) instead. Once you've grappled with the basic notion that "pipes are subshells" and understand what [process substitutions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) do, it is _much_ clearer when written that way. Even the ancient version of Bash that comes with macOS (3.2.something) supports this.

Answer (score 12):

if you use bash

```
while read
do
    if [ -f "$REPLY.bz2" ]
    then
        continue
    else
        filcount=$[$filcount+1]
        bzip $REPLY
    fi
    if [ "$scan" == "1" ]; then bzipint $REPLY
    fi
    echo $filcount    #Correct counting
    echo $zipcount    #Correct counting
    echo $scacount    #Correct counting
    echo $valid       #Equal to 1
done < <(find $loc -name "*.bsp")
```

Comment: +1 much cleaner than passing variables as output; this does essentially the same thing as the pipe version, but with the while loop in the main process.

Answer (score 9):

To **summarize options** for **using `read` at the end of [the conceptual equivalent of] a pipeline** in POSIX-like shells:

To recap: in bash by default and in strictly POSIX-compliant shells always, **all commands in a pipeline run in a *subshell***, so **variables they create or modify won't be visible to the *current* shell** (won't exist after the pipeline ends).

The following **covers `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`, and `sh`** ([mostly] POSIX-features-only shells such as `dash`) and shows **ways of avoiding the creation of a subshell so as to preserve the variables created / modified by `read`**.

<sup>If no minimum version number is given, assume that even "pretty old" versions support it (the features in question have been around for a long time, but I don't know specifically when they were introduced.</sup>

<sup>Note that as a [POSIX-compliant] alternative to the solutions below *you can always capture a command's output in a [temporary] file, and then feed it to `read` as* `< file`, which also avoids subshells.</sup>

---

#### `ksh`, and `zsh`: NO workaround/configuration change needed at all:

The `read` builtin *by default* runs in the *current* shell when used as the *last* command in pipeline.

<sup>Seemingly, `ksh` and `zsh` *by default* run *any* command in the *last* stage of a pipeline in the *current* shell.

Observed in `ksh 93u+` and `zsh 5.0.5`.

If you know specifically in what version this feature was introduced, let me know.</sup>

```
#!/usr/bin/env ksh
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

out= # initialize output variable

# Pipe multiple lines to the `while` loop and collect the values in the output variable.
printf '%s\n' one two three | 
 while read -r var; do
   out+="$var/"
 done

echo "$out" # -> 'one/two/three/'
```

---

#### `bash 4.2+`: use the `lastpipe` shell option

In bash version 4.2 or higher, turning on shell option `lastpipe` causes the last pipeline segment to run in the *current* shell, allowing read to create variables visible to the current shell.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s lastpipe # bash 4.2+: make the last pipeline command run in *current* shell

out=
printf '%s\n' one two three | 
 while read -r var; do
   out+="$var/"
 done

echo "$out" # -> 'one/two/three/'
```

---

#### `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`: use [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution)

Loosely speaking, a process substitution is a way to have a command's output act like a temporary file.

```
out=
while read -r var; do
  out+="$var/"
done < <(printf '%s\n' one two three) # <(...) is the process substitution

echo "$out" # -> 'one/two/three'
```

---

#### `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`: use a [here-string](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument?action=show&redirect=HereString) with a [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution)

```
out=
while read -r var; do
  out+="$var/"
done <<< "$(printf '%s\n' one two three)" # <<< is the here-string operator

echo "$out" # -> 'one/two/three'
```

Note the need to double-quote the command substitution to protect its output from [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html).

---

#### POSIX-compliant solution (`sh`): use a [here-document](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument) with a [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution)

```
#!/bin/sh

out=
while read -r var; do
  out="$out$var/"
done <<EOF # <<EOF ... EOF is the here-doc
$(printf '%s\n' one two three)
EOF

echo "$out" # -> 'one/two/three'
```

Note that, by default, you need to place the ending delimiter - `EOF`, in this case - at the very beginning of the line, and that no characters must follow it.

Comment: So, only shell builtins can affect the shell environment, and only shell builtins running in the current shell at that -- and shells have historically only run builtins directly from the first pipe stage.  So some hypothetical marvelous shell could decide that if there's a single stage running a builtin, that's the stage that it should run directly, but for now you either run the builtin in the first stage or use bash's `lastpipe` option to have it use the last instead.  Cool.  Thanks!  I kinda knew that before, but only kinda.

Comment: @jthill: Turns out that `ksh` and `zsh` already have that magic built in for the _last_ pipeline segment - see my update. The _first_ stage of a pipeline is _always_ run in a _subshell_, even in `ksh` and `zsh`.

Comment: @jthill: Note that wanting the _last_ stage to be in the current shell is the typical use case: you want to capture the _results_ of a pipeline in variables visible to the current shell. Can you tell me what you mean by "if there's a single stage running a builtin"?

Comment: To tap into the middle of the pipeline, say `sort data | while read; do whatever here;: $((subtotal+=someresult)); echo $((someresult)); done | work on the munged stuff; done`

Comment: @jthill: Got it - that would be handy, though I suspect that the _last_ stage is usually the one where you re-enter the "shell world", conceptually speaking.

Answer (score 0):

I landed here because I frequently use this paradigm:

```
find ${yourPath} -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -rd '' eachFile;do 
    echo "${eachFile}" #show all the files, add more code to do real work
done
```

and found out the hard way that variables within the while loop were in a subshell, so this would yield nothing:

```
find ${yourPath} -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -rd '' eachFile;do 
    echo "${eachFile}" #show all the files, add more code to do real work
done
echo "${eachFile}" #we cannot get the last value of eachFile!
```

This still doesn't work:

```
shopt -s lastpipe 
find ${yourPath} -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -rd '' eachFile;do 
    echo "${eachFile}" #show all the files, add more code to do real work
done
echo "${eachFile}" #we cannot get the last value of eachFile; even with lastPipe!
```

This is what works:

```
shopt -s lastpipe 
find ${yourPath} -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -rd '' eachFile;do 
    echo "${eachFile}" #show all the files, add more code to do real work
    latestFile="${eachFile}"
done
echo "${eachFile}" #we cannot get the last value of eachFile; even with lastPipe!
echo "${latestFile}" #but we can get this!
```

My guess is that the `eachFile` variable is still getting created within a subshell, despite the `lastpipe` option; but we can circumvent this by using a variable that is defined/set within the while-loop.