# Modifying a global variable works, but not when a pipe is used

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line, substitution

Changing a global variable in a bash script works perfectly. But when a pipe is used it stops working as expected.

This works:

##### pf_test1:

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "1) MyGlobal=${MyGlobal}"
source pf_test2
echo "2) MyGlobal=${MyGlobal}"
change_global
echo "3) MyGlobal=${MyGlobal}"
inc_global 2
echo "4) MyGlobal=${MyGlobal}"
```

##### pf_test2:

```
#! /bin/bash
MyGlobal=100

function change_global() {
  MyGlobal=200
}
function inc_global() {
  RC=$1
  MyGlobal=$((MyGlobal + RC))
}
```

Output is:

```
$ ./pf_test1
1) MyGlobal=
2) MyGlobal=100
3) MyGlobal=200
4) MyGlobal=202
```

But changing the pf_test1 by adding a pipe, causes the the global variable not to be changed any more:

##### updated pf_test1

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "1) MyGlobal=${MyGlobal}"
source pf_test2
echo "2) MyGlobal=${MyGlobal}"
change_global | tee pf_ja.log
echo "3) MyGlobal=${MyGlobal}"
inc_global 2 | tee pf_ja.log
echo "4) MyGlobal=${MyGlobal}"
```

##### Output showing the issue

```
./pf_test1
1) MyGlobal=
2) MyGlobal=100
3) MyGlobal=100
4) MyGlobal=100
```

I don't understand why this fails. Any ideas?

And any solutions?

PS This is on Ubuntu

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

**Update:** I changed the pf_test1 as shown in the comments:

```
echo "1) MyGlobal=${MyGlobal}"
source pf_test2
echo "2) MyGlobal=${MyGlobal}"
change_global > >(tee pf_ja.log)
echo "3) MyGlobal=${MyGlobal}"
inc_global 2 > >(tee pf_ja.log)
echo "4) MyGlobal=${MyGlobal}"
```

but I also added echo statements in pf_test2:

```
MyGlobal=100

function change_global() {
  echo "in change_global"
  MyGlobal=200
}
function inc_global() {
  echo "in inc_global $1"
  RC=$1
  MyGlobal=$((MyGlobal + RC))
}
```

The output is:

```
$ ./pf_test1
1) MyGlobal=
2) MyGlobal=100
3) MyGlobal=200
4) MyGlobal=202
$ in change_global
in inc_global 2
```

The output from the echos are done *after* pf_test1 ends. And the content of pf_ja.log is just the last line:

```
in inc_global 2
```

Comment: All components of a pipeline are normally run in (separate) subshells; any changes made in a subshell do not affect the parent. For recent versions of bash [the _last_ component _may_ be run in the parent](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html) but this doesn't apply to your cases. PS: in bash (but not all other shells) your `inc_global` can be simplified to `(( MyGlobal += $1 ))` or `let MyGlobal += $1`.

Comment: In bash (but not all other shells), you can use process substitution instead of a pipe, like `change_global > >(tee pf_ja.log)`. See [BashFAQ #24: "I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) and ["Variables getting reset after the while read loop that reads from a pipeline"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313491/variables-getting-reset-after-the-while-read-loop-that-reads-from-a-pipeline) (though that's about reading from a pipe, not writing to it).

Comment: This sort of fixes it, but breaks something else. I used the "> >(tee pf_ja.log)" and the MyGlobal update works. But only the last bit of the stdout in the functions are saved in the log file. I updated the question to show that.

Comment: Don't use POSIX shells for anything other than trivial management of the execution of external commands. The rules for variable substitution and visibility are awful. POSIX shells are not a sane programming language. I say this as someone who has been programming for four decades and fell in love with Unix in the early 1980's before Bash even existed. The behavior you describe in this question is only one of many odd behaviors that POSIX shells exhibit.

Comment: Putting `function` in front of `function inc_global()` is doing nothing useful, it's just making your code less portable. get rid of it and just declare functions as `inc_global()`.

Comment: *"only the last bit of the stdout ... are saved"*. Don't have the time to analyze your complete issue, but `tee -a` or `>> logFile` may help? Good luck.